# The viewController that is present (_: animated: completion :) is forced to be closed

Tags: ios, swift

```
present (A_controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

With A_controller displayed at the top, close the application with the Home button, and when you start the application again, A_controller will be closed automatically.
  What is the probable cause of the A_controller closing automatically?

Comment: Perhaps your app was killed in the background.